# MySQL Anti-sort

Tags: mysql, sorting

Recently I had a task with the need of unusual result set.

Lets imagine next data source:

```
[level]
[1]
[2]
[1]
[3]
[2]
[3]
[1]
```

From this list I need to select values in next order: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1

Using regular MySQL sorting all I can get is group result by this column, so I'm getting something like `SORT BY level asc` 1,1,1,2,2,3,3.

I tried conditional sorts, but it doesn't seem to help, the core of the sorting itself is the opposite what I'm trying to get - I want it evenly spread, not grouped. But in the same place I need a strict order to be preserved.

For now I just ran out of thoughts, and will appreciate any kind of advices

**UPDATE**

there are no other column I can use for additional sorting. Of course there are a lot more columns in the table, but none of those are related to this one (level).

I know I can do all kind of tricks in application code later, but I wanted to get some insight whether this is possible at all.

So far I've tried next without any luck:

```
set @a = 0;
...
order by
 case
 when (@a <= 3) then level = @a := @a + 1
 when (@a > 3) then level = @a := 1
end desc
```

I know why that didn't work. I just tried to update what my though process was.

If you wonder why I need that, lets say that I want to limit my result set to 3 later and be sure to get items of three levels. Group doesn't work for me, because I may want to also apply additional sorting on top of this one.

Comment: You will probably need to implement this custom sorting in code.

Comment: For a "strict" order, there *must* be a second column by which to order. MySQL reserves the right to rearrange rows, so what *once* came in first, might come second when the table has been populated. Is there such a second column? And is it always only 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: are there any other fields that could be used? e.g. may `sort by mod(otherfield, 3), level`?

Comment: I can see one way of doing that. But it requires some programming outside of the SQL query. Store the 1s, the 2s and the 3s in separate variables. Than do a `for loop` creating a new array that has the "1,2,3" pattern. ie in VB : `for i = 0 to ubound(Ones) step  3; Myarray(i) = Ones(i/3); Myarray(i+1) = Twos(i/3); Myarray(i+2) = Threes(i/3); End For`

Comment: @MarcB please review my update, maybe that can be more helpful to understand what I was trying to do;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you put it, it doesn't even make much sense to sort. You could simply do (here assuming you are using PHP from your other questions):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT level, COUNT(level) FROM table GROUP BY level ORDER BY level");
$levels = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)
    $levels[$row[0]] = $row[1];

while (array_sum($levels))
     foreach ($levels as $level => &$count)
         if ($count)
         {
             $count--;
             echo "{$level},";
         }
```

Observing the pointlessness of having a table like this, I presume there is some other field in your table you can use to sort this stuff the way you want. For example:

```
[username], [level]
foo         1
bar         2
foo         2
bar         3
foo         3
bar         1
```

In this case you can use:

```
SELECT level FROM table ORDER BY username, level
```

In this example even though `username` was not selected as part of the result, it can be used to sort it and you will have `1,2,3,1,2,3` as result.

Comment: Maybe I really did a bad job describing what I want. The reason why I want to have sorting like that - is I need to limit the result set to 3 and be sure that I will get items with level 1, 2 and 3. does that make sense?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY level SORT BY level LIMIT 3`. It should give you only one result from each level.